# Dyamic rendering of graph API for python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-theory

I wish to find a library which is able to render the evolution of a graph during the processing phase. Therefore you would be able to see the graph visually growing and/or pruned according to the current results processed by the classes. Is there any library for python which has the following requirements?

Comment: By "graph" do you mean the [graph of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) or [graph-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) graph?

Comment: @unutbu by graophs i mean graph theory graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a changing dataset (as opposed to the graph-theoretic type) [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) can do this. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html?highlight=funcanimation) for the animation functionality is lengthy, but there are many examples at:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/

If you are talking about the other type of a "graph", you can use [`networkx`](http://networkx.github.io/) to manipulate and render the graph with fixed positions. Underneath it uses `matplotlib` as its drawing backend.